# Memory game with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a small problem that could ruin the game. Once you click a card you need to search for the other card with the same picture right? but the problem is you can also double click and it will think you found the other card. Anyone know how o solf this problem?

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards .card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("click", () => {
    card.classList.add("clicked");

    if (counter === 0) {
      firstSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
      counter++;
    } else {
      secondSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
      counter = 0;

      if (firstSelection === secondSelection) {
        const correctCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card[meme='" + firstSelection + "']");

        
        score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML) + 1
          if (score.innerHTML >= 8)
        correctCards[0].classList.add("checked");
        correctCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
        correctCards[1].classList.add("checked");                       
        correctCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
      } else {
        const incorrectCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.clicked");

        incorrectCards[0].classList.add("red");
        incorrectCards[1].classList.add("red");                  
        setTimeout(() => {
          incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("red");         
          incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
          incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("red");
          incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
        }, 600);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: how about adding a simple check if the clicked card is not the same as the previously selected card?

Comment: Just check if the card have the class `clicked` on it. If so, return to reject to the click.

Answer (score -1):

Although there is a double click event (dblclick), it is not supported by all browsers. The way around this is to test for double clicks within your click event handlers and use a timer function (to see if two clicks happened within a select amount of time). I use 300ms for the timer, but you may have to play around with that a bit.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards .card");
let clickCount = 0;
cards.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("click", () => {
    
    clickCount ++;
    if (clickCount == 1) {
        clickTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            clickCount = 0;
            //single click functionality here
            card.classList.add("clicked");

            if (counter === 0) {
              firstSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
              counter++;
            } else {
              secondSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
              counter = 0;
        
              if (firstSelection === secondSelection) {
                const correctCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card[meme='" + firstSelection + "']");
        
                
                score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML) + 1
                  if (score.innerHTML >= 8)
                correctCards[0].classList.add("checked");
                correctCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
                correctCards[1].classList.add("checked");                       
                correctCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
              } else {
                const incorrectCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.clicked");
        
                incorrectCards[0].classList.add("red");
                incorrectCards[1].classList.add("red");                  
                setTimeout(() => {
                  incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("red");         
                  incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
                  incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("red");
                  incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
                }, 600);
              }
            }
        }, 300);
    } else if (clickCount == 2) {
        clearTimeout(clickTimer);
        clickCount = 0;
        console.log("This was a double click!");
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set 2 global vars `firstClickedCard` and `secondClickedCard`, and on `click`, assign the card `element` (`event.currentTarget`) to these variables. Then on second click, check `if (secondClickedCard === firstClickedCard)` before any of your other logic, and reject the click event if this is true.

This should verify if the actual clicked *element* (not just the `meme` attribute) are the same or not.

*Note: this is untested, and would be easier to verify if your question included a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).*

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards .card");

var firstClickedCard;
var secondClickedCard;

cards.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    card.classList.add("clicked");

    if (counter === 0) {
      firstClickedCard = e.currentTarget;
      firstSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
      counter++;
    } else {
      secondClickedCard = e.currentTarget;

      // reject this click
      if (secondClickedCard === firstClickedCard) {
          secondClickedCard = null;
          return false;
      }

      secondSelection = card.getAttribute("meme");
      counter = 0;

      if (firstSelection === secondSelection) {
        const correctCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card[meme='" + firstSelection + "']");

        
        score.innerHTML = parseInt(score.innerHTML) + 1
          if (score.innerHTML >= 8)
        correctCards[0].classList.add("checked");
        correctCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
        correctCards[1].classList.add("checked");                       
        correctCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
      } else {
        const incorrectCards = document.querySelectorAll(".card.clicked");

        incorrectCards[0].classList.add("red");
        incorrectCards[1].classList.add("red");                  
        setTimeout(() => {
          incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("red");         
          incorrectCards[0].classList.remove("clicked");
          incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("red");
          incorrectCards[1].classList.remove("clicked");
        }, 600);
      }
    }
  });
});
```